# SceneKit transform to another coordinate

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit, arkit

There is the thing.In ARKit, I have a mark object's anchor and many cube object. And Save the mark object's anchor's transform(In Coordinate A), and cube's anchor's transform (In Coordinate A).

When I reset ARKit, I got the new transform(In Coordinate B) about mark object.So I need to calculate the transform between A & B to get the relationship. Then the cube's anchor's transform use the relationship, to calculate a new transform which is the cube's transform in (In Coordinate B).

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you have the position and orientation of an object in a session, then you stop the session (i.e close the app) then restart it again and want to keep the object in the same place?

If so then no, you can't do this. ARKit doesn't provide persistent tracking - though it's coming.

Comment: Yesh, I know ARKit doesn't provide persistent tracking. So I use something to help arkit do some transform, then persistent tracking. May be I could use 2D image tracking(ARKit 1.5) to do that

Comment: That will only tell you that you recognise what is in front of you. It doesn't given you the pose parameters between your current session and the previous one. This is quite a difficult problem - lots of people are actively working on it.

Comment: Copy that. What do you mean though it's coming ?  In iOS12？

Comment: Well there are some startups - like 6D.ai - and I've seen a couple of demos from individuals. There have been rumours that Apple is planning on releasing something. 6D are doing a private beta later this year I think.